# Getting unresolved reference: ImmutableList error

Tags: kotlin, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

Getting unresolved reference: ImmutableList error . what library do I need to import to remove this error? original code is from here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#show-products

and android studio did not offer a library to import

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to add:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable:0.3.5")
```

to your dependencies

Comment: now i get "Unresolved reference: of"

Comment: Oh, you probably are talking about Guava's immutableList, well then you probably should take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48378440/15749574, btw, why won't you simply use a list.of() ? Lists are also not mutable and don't require additional dependencies

Comment: I see - I'm just getting the code the official Google documentation: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#show-products

Comment: You (or other people in the future) could also look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72616597/15749574